# How I can display the form data in the same page without submit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form in HTML and I want to display the form text input data on the same page but before pressing the submit button.
Mean, When Users put the data in the form it must display below the form on same page.
It's mean that I want to show all data before submitting the form.

I know this code will not work as i want

```
var strText = document.getElementById("textone");
document.write(strText.value);
var strText1 = document.getElementById("textTWO");
document.write(strText1.value);
}
```

Comment: It would be fairly simple to set up an eventlistener ("oninput") on the text-input-fields in question, but what would be the point, as the text to be submitted remains visible in the original input fields anyway?

Comment: I edited my answer and it now does what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it by directly manipulating the DOM:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('textInput');
const textElement = document.getElementById('displayText');

function updateValue(e) {
  textElement.textContent = e.target.value;
}
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textInput">
<p>value from input:</p>
<div id="displayText"></div>
```

There are also javascript libraries like [VueJS](https://vuejs.org/) and [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) that can help you do this more easily and efficiently.

This is an example of something like what you would want to do in VueJS: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/index.html

Comment: Thank You very Much, It gives me an idea to perform my task.

Comment: Np. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

I've prepared an example of general functioning, I hope you like it. It may not be exactly what you want, but if it is, please tell me.

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");

const nameInput = document.getElementById("nameInput");
const emailInput = document.getElementById("emailInput");

const nameOutput = document.getElementById("nameOutput");
const emailOutput = document.getElementById("emailOutput");

let nameSpan = document.getElementById("name");
let emailSpan = document.getElementById("email");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(`NAME: ${nameInput.value}, EMAİL : ${emailInput.value}`)

  // select name , mail 
  nameSpan.innerText = nameInput.value;
  emailSpan.innerText = emailInput.value;

  // clear ınputs 
  nameInput.value = "";
  emailInput.value = ""
})

showData();

function showData() {
  nameInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    nameOutput.value = e.target.value;
  })
  emailInput.addEventListener("keyup", e => {
    emailOutput.value = e.target.value;
  })
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="nameInput" placeholder="your name">
  <input type="text" id="emailInput" placeholder="your email">
  <button type="submit" id="getInputValue"> Get Input Value </button>
</form>

<div id="values" style="margin-top: 100px;">
  <input type="text" placeholder="NAME" id="nameOutput">
  <input type="text" placeholder="EMAİL" id="emailOutput">
</div>


<div>
  <p>Your name : <span id="name"></span></p>
  <p>Your email : <span id="email"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Working clearly here, not at my end
But it is not what I need. Want to show all form data in the simple text below the form